# ansible using loop and multiple variables

Tags: ansible

i am using "**shell:**" to get some data by looping over "**with_items:**" and registering it as another variable.
Later using "**lineinfile:**" i am trying to apply the contents of earlier variable,but  not able to use "**{{variable.stdout}}**" as it is showing as undefined in "**with_items:**"

Is there a way to tell ansible that for "**variable.stdout**" don't look in "**with_items:**"

```
---
- include_vars: /root/template.yml

- name: Getting MAC
  shell: "cat /sys/class/net/{{item.name}}/address"
  register: mac
  with_items:
  - "{{ interfaces_ipv4 }}"

- name: Setting MAC
   lineinfile:
   state=present
   dest=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{item.name}}
   regexp='^HWADDR=.*'
   line="HWADDR={{mac.stdout}}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ interfaces_ipv4 }}"
  tags:
   - set_mac
```

Contents of variable file

```
#/root/tempplate.yml

- name: ens35
  bootproto: dhcp
- name: ens34
  bootproto: none
```

When executing:

TASK: [mac | Setting MAC] *****************************************************
fatal: [192.168.211.146] => **One or more undefined variables: 'dict' object has no attribute 'stdout'**

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Comment: Please give strong consideration to using Ansible's `template` module instead of `lineinfile`. The latter is an antipattern; it tends towards substantial complexity and pain.

Answer (score 9):

`register` works a bit differently when used inside loops (see [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)). In that case, your variable will have a `results` item, which is a list with the result of each iteration as items. Each item in that list will also have an `item` item, with the element iterated on.

For example:

```
mac: {
    msg: "All items completed",
    results: [
        {
          changed: True,
          stdout: "some_stdout",
          item: {
               name: "some_name1"
          }
        },
        {
          changed: True,
          stdout: "some_stdout2",
          item: {
               name: "some_name2"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

You could then loop over that instead of the original list:

```
- name: Setting MAC
  lineinfile:
     state=present
     dest=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{item.item.name}}
     regexp='^HWADDR=.*'
     line="HWADDR={{item.stdout}}"
  with_items: mac.results
  tags:
   - set_mac
```